# How to remove an interval of time series for just 1 of multiple variables in 'R'?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, time-series

I have two quarterly time series. One0 starts in 1957 the other in 1996. I want to plot (and later use for regression) the numbers from 1996 of both.
I either have to use two different datasets or can I just copy the 1996 start series into the other one in Excel (CSV format) and remove the ones from before 1996 in R?

`ggplot` doesn't seem very friendly with two datasets. That's why I wanted to merge them. But it doesn't work either as the one starting in 1996 then just starts in 1957

I want to plot both (doesn't have to be ggplot) to see their relationship but either 'R' tells me to use 'aes' when I use two datasets (despite that 'aes' is there) or simply nothing happens when I run the plot function with both variables (unfiltered) from the same dataset.

Comment: can you provide a minimal data example using `dput` please?

Comment: I have exchange rates for 1957-2018 but net current account from 1996-2018. How do I remove the observations from 1957-1996 in the exchange rate data to make a proper regression?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that plotting 2 data frames with ggplot is best done like this.

```
a<- data.frame(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6))
b<- data.frame(c(2,4,6), c(8,10,12))

ggplot(data=NULL) 
+ geom_point(aes(x=a[,1],y=a[,2]), color="blue") 
+ geom_point(aes(x=b[,1], y=b[,2]), color="red")
```

Hope I have understood your question correctly, but i'm not entirely sure